# Android: add padding right to a bitmap

Tags: java, android, selector

I need add padding right to my arrow bitmap
There is a easy way to set this?

[image]

code:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
  <bitmap android:src="@drawable/img_0002" android:gravity="right" />
</item>
```

thanks!

**Edit:**

Layout Code:

```
        <LinearLayout style="@style/menu_container">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_services"
            style="@style/menu_item">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                style="@style/font_menu"
                android:text="@string/section_menu_services" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_social" 
            style="@style/menu_item">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                style="@style/font_menu"
                android:text="@string/section_menu_social"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Styles:

```
    <style name="menu_container">
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerHorizontal">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_centerVertical">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_menu_container</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
</style>

<style name="menu_item">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_menu_drawable</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Are you looking for android:paddingRight?

Comment: @Heinrisch i added "android:paddingRight" in everywhere and did not work

Comment: Everywhere means where? You should post every layouts code.

Comment: @PareshMayani everywhere means, everywhere in the selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the more easy and dirty way to fix it. I added a transparent block in the right side of the icon. I'm ashamed about that...

Answer (score 0):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:right="16sp">
            <bitmap android:src="@drawable/new_switch" android:gravity="center"/>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

The item node inside a layerlist can be given padding